# How can I replace values of different rows and columns with condition?

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` named `data1`, and I have to replace the values of the `columns` `EntAge` and `Agemenar` `if EntAge<Agemenar` `EntAge is Agemenar` `&&` `Agemenar is EntAge`

Could you help me please?

I tried this:

```
r <- replace(data1$Entage, data1$Entage < data1$Agemenar, data1$Agemenar)
data1$Entage <- r
```

Comment: Does it throw a warning? If so it means that the `values = data1$Agemenar` vector is bigger than the vector of values where the condition is `TRUE`. Try `i <- which(data1$Entage < data1$Agemenar)` then `r <- replace(data1$Entage, i, data1$Agemenar[i])`. Finally, assign back `data1$Entage <- r`.

Answer (score 0):

Working in the `tidyverse` will make this easy. This is assuming you want to replace EntAge with Agemenar if EntAge < Agemenar. It was not entirely clear to me.

```
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data1 %>%
  mutate(EntAge = if_else(EntAge < Agemenar, Agemenar, EntAge)
```